# How to show price in two places in product details page in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In product details page, How to show the final price in two places?

I have tried but it shows once.

Thanks for advance!!!

Comment: What you want to do? Please write in detail.

Comment: I need to show the product price in two places ( After the name of product and after add to cart button)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184080/magento-2-duplicate-pricing-block-to-show-in-2-places-on-the-product-page

Answer (score 0):

You can write following code in product view page template file.

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

Comment: Good, It is working!!!